# Invitation link to a site in multisite network does not work?

Tags: customization, users

I have a WP Multisite, and when a subsite want's to invite a user to the site it will send out an invitation link which looks like this:
`https://example.com/testsite/wp-activate.php?key=70f4aeac6db778e4`

The problem is that this will redirect me to the login page immidiatly, not show me the Activation page with the password. And the user will not be activated.

However, if I edit the link to remove the `testsite`:
`https://example.com/wp-activate.php?key=70f4aeac6db778e4` it will work just fine. And the user will be activated on the subsite.

This is a weird issue, and the workaround would be to hook into the link that's sent out in the email to remove the subsite before the email is delivered.

Anyone know what hook to use to edit this URL?

Thank you!

Comment: I was about to say someone else [was having the same problem yesterday](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/369134), but it was you :-)

Comment: [Here's the relevant code.](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L939) There's no obvious filter for the URL, unless you replace the whole function with wpmu_signup_blog_notification or edit the URL when you're assembling the email in wpmu_signup_blog_notification_email. But the code I've linked to should already generate network URLs for path-based subsites, so something's going wrong here.

Comment: **Do not repost the same question daily to gain more views**, it is unacceptable behaviour. I have closed your original question as a duplicate of this one, but be warned, as a low reputation user you can get picked up by stack exchanges automated spam protection. If you didn't get responses you should edit and improve your question, do not create a duplicate question. Also remember, deleted questions and answers are just hidden, the system and moderators can still see them.

Comment: @TomJNowell In fairness they are slightly different questions: the old one is 'why isn't this working' and this one is 'how do I change the URL generated to work around the problem'. But it probably is the same issue: wpmu_signup_blog_notification() is generating the wrong URL.

Comment: Yes exactly why I created new post, as I found the issue. This question is more specific. But I will keep that in mind next time! Thanks for the help @Rup